# Creating a scikit-learn contribution package

Tags: python, git, scikit-learn

I am creating a new classifier and wanting to add it into sklearn library.

I am following a template provided by sklearn but I'm stuck at Step 1. Step 1 is "Download and setup your repository" (see link below).

https://sklearn-template.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html

I don't understand what is Step 1 for?

When I run the first code:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/project-template.git
```

why am I getting an error message:

```
 File "<ipython-input-5-cc43960fed74>", line 1
    $ git clone https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/project-template.git
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda.

Comment: The dollar sign is not part of the text you should copy and paste, it's just a sigil to indicate that you would paste this at the shell prompt (in a Bourne-compatible shell). This is a common beginner FAQ.

Comment: Thanks tripleee. Do you happen to have a rough idea what’s Step 1 for?

Comment: Well yes, `git clone` fetches a local copy for you to work on. But if you are not at all familiar with Git, probably reserve some time to familiarize yourself with it.

Comment: Ok thanks tripleee, I will have a look.